# Google custom search - result page doesn't display any results when I am using AMP

Tags: speed, plugins, google-search, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website and I am using AMP plugin to make the website AMP compatible. The mode template that I am using is native.
I have an issue related to google custom search and AMP. On my website I have several google custom search forms that should search for content from my website but when I am using with AMP the page results doesn't return any results. I don't have any errors in console and AMP plugin marks my page as a valid AMP page. So where's the issue?

I have to mention that I am using AMP + GLUE + YOAST

Any of you had this problem? How can I use Google Custom Search and AMP in the same time?

Any response is much appreciated.
Thank you guys!